# Convert existing app to API calls in php

Tags: php, web-services, cakephp

Sorry if it is re-posting. I have an web application which provides course materials and user can use that. We have got some clients and each client has its own copy of code. We need to change this completely. Each client will have separate web design and we need to give all functionality through API calls. I prefer cakephp. 
How to make API version for my web application with proper authentication ?
Which one we should provide - SOAP or REST ?
Please guide me.

Comment: This question is way too broad. But REST is most likely what you want.

Comment: Refer this http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/rest.html